# Shortcuts to launch game with different launch options in Steam

Tags: steam

I am trying to create shortcuts for Arma 3 so I can quickly launch the game with and without mods, so I need to create at least 2 shortcuts, one for vanilla and one for mods.

But when I created the shortcut with Steam, I noticed it's a .url file. I managed to add the launch options using this:

```
URL=steam://rungameid/107410//-nosplash -world=empty -mod=@......
```

What I don't like about this is that when launching the game using that .url file shortcut, Steam will open a warning message saying Allow Arma 3 to open with optional command line "-nosplash -world=empty........"?

**Is there a way to disable that warning or a better way to create multiple steam shortcuts with different launch options?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can skip the message by using

```
C:\Path\To\Steam.exe -applaunch 107410 -nosplash -and -so -on
```

*(Change the path to match your Steam.exe path)*

The warning message exists for the URL so websites cannot launch games for you using parameters you do not want.

Comment: Will that work if steam is already running?

Comment: @peterg32 It works for me, so I would assume yes.