# Can I play Beyond Earth without Steam?

Tags: steam, civilization-beyond-earth

I looked at the [Beyond Earth , game site](https://www.civilization.com/en/games/civilization-beyond-earth/) and it does not say anything about steam.  I searched here and [found sometimes you can't play if steam is not happy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190104/skip-mantle-question-when-launching-game/190105#190105).  Is this game dependent on steam (*as some have been*) or is steam an option?

Answer (score 2):

You need Steam to install and play the game. Even the boxed version is just a Steam key and some files to make the download easier.

Beyond Earth does work in offline mode, so once installed you can still play it if you lose your internet connection or Steam's servers have issues.