# Steam beta shortcuts

Tags: steam, dota-2

Dota 2 recently release the option to start your game in the Reborn Beta. Usually, to do this you have to go to your library and hit the play button in the Steam client for it to give you the option. When I run my desktop shortcut it doesn't give me an option and automatically opens plain Dota 2.

Is there a way to either make a new icon for the Beta, make the Beta default, or let me choose when I click the icon?

P.S:
[Shortcuts to launch game with different launch options in Steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132591/shortcuts-to-launch-game-with-different-launch-options-in-steam)
does not quite answer my question.
Also, I'm running Win8 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a shortcut to `(PathToSteamFolder)\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\game\bin\win64\dota2.exe` if you are running a 64 bit OS or `(PathToSteamFolder)\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\game\bin\win32\dota2.exe` if running 32 bit OS.

Comment: This *should* work, but let me know if it doesn't, as I can't test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

open dota2  in library >  right click dota2 in game list on the left side > click "create desktop shortcut"

Comment: The asker already said that he tried this, but it did not work.